# How to install postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1 on Ubuntu 14.04(Trusty Tahr)?

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, synaptic

I get the following error when trying to install postgres-9.4-postgis-2.1 on Ubuntu 14.04(Trusty Tahr):

```
Depends: libgdal1 (>= 1.9.0) but it is not installable
```

I also tried to install the package via synaptic but nothing. I have installed libgdal1-1.10.1-grass and libgdal1h but the error persisted.

Although One possible solution may be is to install the libgdal1 from saucy repo instead of downloading it from trusty, but what should I do to download it from saucy repo??

Also tell me if there is any other possible solution.Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You should install the meta-package `gdal` (and pretty much all other FOSS4G) from the [ubuntugis-unstable PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable/+index?field.series_filter=trusty):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgres-9.4-postgis-2.1
```

Comment: `gdal` not available for vivid yet

Comment: Yes [it is](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/gdal-bin). But the question is on 14.04 in any case.

Comment: Thanks Luis! After installing `gdal-bin` I still get the error about the 'gibgdal1 (>= 1.9.0)'

Comment: What happens if you run `sudo apt-get install libgdal1h` ?

Comment: I tried that previously (before knowing about `gdal-bin`), but still got the 1.9.0 error when trying to install postgis.

Comment: The only explanation for your case is the presence of an older version of gdal installed manually.

Comment: I think my case is the same as the OP. As I understand it `libgdal1h` replaces `libgdal1`, but the postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1 package is only looking for the dependency `libgdal1 (>= 1.9.0)'; I assume the addition of the 'h' is throwing it off.

Comment: Should be postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1 instead of postgres-9.4-postgis-2.1

Answer (score 3):

This solved it for me. I needed to update /etc/apt/sources.list.save and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/postgresql.list

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main
```

to

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main
```

Comment: How is this related?

Comment: It works that way, but ended up installing 9.5

Answer (score 2):

This guy seems to have been able to create a docker image with your exact setup (trusty & 9.4-2.1):
https://hub.docker.com/r/kartoza/postgis/

Looking at the comments, he/she also come across the libgdal1/libgdal1h problem  and seems to have solved it:

https://github.com/kartoza/docker-postgis/blob/9.4-2.1/Dockerfile

Maybe you could install via docker or follow the exact steps in that docker file?
I'll update my answer here with the exact steps if you are successful with them.

Answer (score 1):

**Add Respository to sources.list**

You'll need to replace the nickname below with what you are running. Note to replace the word trusty with whatever version lsb states

Helper on ​http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/

For trusty (14.04)

> sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt
>   trusty-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'

**Add Keys**

> wget --quiet -O - http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ACCC4CF8.asc
>   | sudo apt-key add - sudo apt-get update

**Install**

The following will install postgresql 9.5, PostGIS 2.2, PGAdmin3, pgRouting 2.1 and additional supplied modules including the adminpack extension:

> sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.2

Answer (score 0):

If you build from source you can avoid the dependency on `gdal` by using the `--without-raster` option.

This means you can't use the 'CREATE EXTENSION postgis;' shortcut. [more info](http://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html#install_short_version)

Prerequisites that I have listed:

```
apt-get install libgeos-3.4.2 libgeos-dev libxml2-dev

wget http://download.osgeo.org/proj/proj-4.9.2.tar.gz
tar xfvz proj-4.9.2.tar.gz
cd proj-4.9.2
./configure
make && make install
```

Postgis:

```
wget http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/source/postgis-2.1.8.tar.gz
tar xfvz postgis-2.1.8.tar.gz
cd postgis-2.1.8
./configure --with-pgconfig=/usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/pg_config --without-raster
make && make install
```

Now there was a problem for me in that the postgis library can't see the proj library, as can be seen from the 'not found' when executing `ldd /usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/lib/postgis-2.1.so`
The solution was to softlink it:

```
ln /usr/local/lib/libproj.so.9.1.0 /usr/lib/libproj.so.9
```

Then you have to execute 'postgis.sql' against your database (and possibly others; see link to installation steps above)

```
psql -d yourdatabase -f /usr/share/postgresql/9.4/contrib/postgis-2.1/postgis.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the problem; I had an incorrect pgdg.list in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ (the distribution codename wasn't matching my ubuntu version).
After removing that, doing `apt-get update`, it installed correctly (either from ubuntugis or from the main ubuntu repository, not sure).