# How to install PostGIS on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-installation, sudo, database

I tried:

```
gsamaras@gsamaras:~$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1-postgis
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-9.1-postgis
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-9.1-postgis'
```

and:

```
gsamaras@gsamaras:~$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1'
```

which I found in [UsersWikiPost](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS21UbuntuPGSQL93Apt), but both attempts gave:

> E: Unable to locate package

---

This [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615767/how-to-install-postgresql-9-4-postgis-2-1-on-ubuntu-14-04trusty-tahr) is relevant, but when I tried it's top answer, I am getting warnings about not using the stable version.

Comment: Can you please add the exact warnings/errors you are getting?

Comment: With pleasure @Ron.

Comment: Did you add pgdg repositories in your `sources.list` file as given in the UsersWikiPost?

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `grep -r 'apt.postgresql.org' /etc/apt`. And you should run `sudo apt-get update` before installing `postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1`

Comment: @Ron no, I am trying that now.

Comment: @Ron it turns out that I had to add the keys too! Bravo, you really helped. Are you going to answer or should I delete the question? A.B. it's solved now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PostgreSQL Global Development Group (PGDG) maintains an [APT repository](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt) of PostgreSQL packages for Debian and Ubuntu.

To install in 14.04:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt trusty-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
wget --quiet -O - http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1 pgadmin3 postgresql-contrib
```